# Create object without saving it with Grails Build Test Data Plugin

Tags: testing, grails

I need to create an instance of an object passing all constraints, without saving it.

Build Test Data 'build' method saves the instance.

Is there an optional parameter or another method of the plugin to get the 'same' object without saving it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just call `buildWithoutSave` instead of `build`.